# windows phone 7 ListBox event confusion

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox

The app is like a small dictionary. I have a listbox and a textbox. The list box is already filled with words and when there is any entry in the textbox the listbox is refilled again with words starting with the letters in the textbox. I have a listbox SelectionChanged event implemented when the user clicks on a word its meaning appears. The problem is when user selects a word from the list and then types something in the textbox, listBox SelectionChanged event is called i dont want this to happen because at this point of time my listbox's selected item is empty.I would like to have a event that is fired only when user selects something from the listbox. It should not be fired when the content of the listbox changes. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use**

**1.if (lstWords.SelectedItem != null)**

**2.lstWords.SelectedIndex = -1;**

**for e.g.**  following is the source code for text changed event and list selection change event

```
     private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (textBox1.Text.ToString().Equals(""))
            {
                XmlDictionaryRepository test = new XmlDictionaryRepository();
                lstWords.ItemsSource = test.GetWordList(categorySelected,xmlFileName);
            }
            else
            {
                XmlDictionaryRepository test = new XmlDictionaryRepository();
                lstWords.ItemsSource = test.GetMatchWordList(categorySelected, textBox1.Text.ToString(),xmlFileName);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), (((PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual).Content).ToString(), MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }
    }

    private void lstWords_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            if (lstWords.SelectedItem != null)
            {             

                string wordSelected = ((Glossy_Test.Dictionary)(lstWords.SelectedItem)).Word;
                if (lstWords.SelectedItem != null)
                {
                    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format("/DescribeWord.xaml?param1={0}&param2={1}", wordSelected, categorySelected), UriKind.Relative));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), (((PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual).Content).ToString(), MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }
        finally
        {
            // lstWords.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }

    }
```